# Хранение конфигов в Git

Tags: git

Есть 2 каталога с конфигами которые хотелось бы хранить в git, это /etc/httpd/conf.d и /opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/
Я создал проект в корне и создал файл .gitignore

```
# cat /.gitignore
/*
!opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/**
!/etc/httpd/conf.d/**
```

Но по команде `git add .` ни чего в репозиторий не добавляется, подскажите что ни так? Или какие есть еще пути решения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем `.gitignore`:

```
*
```

А добавлять файлы и директории с помощью:

```sh
# git add -f /etc/httpd/conf.d
# git add -f /opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration
```